# Telegraf unable to connect to InfluxDB

Tags: docker, influxdb, telegraf

I am new to docker, influx grafana etc. I got grafana and influxdb running, but seems to be unable to connect telegraf to influxdb. I followed many guides, but I am missing something.

I created a Telegraf conf file on E:\docker\containers\telegraf and try to use it with:

`docker run -v e:/docker/containers/telegraf/:/etc/telegraf/telegraf:ro telegraf`

But I keep getting the following error:

```
2017/05/13 20:32:39 I! Using config file: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
2017-05-13T20:32:39Z E! Database creation failed: Post 
http://localhost:8086/query?db=&q=CREATE+DATABASE+%22telegraf%22: dial tcp 
[::1]:8086:
getsockopt: connection refused
```

I have this in the influxdb output part of the conf file:

```
[[outputs.influxdb]]
# urls = ["udp://localhost:8089"] # UDP endpoint example
urls = ["http://10.0.75.1:8086"] # required
database = "telegraf" # required

retention_policy = ""
write_consistency = "any"

timeout = "5s"
#username = "telegraf"
#password = "telegraf"
```

If you look ad the urls, it does not seem to read the conf file. I just keeps trying to connect to localhost. (localhost:8083 and 10.0.75.1:8083 both open the influxdb webpage)

Comment: What version of Docker? What is the host system OS? How was Docker installed on the host?

Comment: Docker version: 17.0.3.1, installed on Win 10 with the MSI file.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the mapping and / or E drive is now allowed to be mapped in Docker for Windows.

First, your mapping doesn't appear correct. If you have a file of `telegraf.conf` at `e:/docker/containers/telegraf/` then your current mapping will end up with the file at `/etc/telegraf/telegraf/telegraf.conf` which is one extra `telegraf` folder deep. The error states it is looking for `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf`. In this case, it is likely using a default `telegraf.conf`.

Next, I believe the Docker on Windows doesn't allow mapping of drives other than C by default. Check the shared drive settings to make sure that E is allowed to be mapped (an article I found that shows this is at https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c).

After fixing both of these errors, if it still persists, I would get into the container with `docker exec` and confirm that the `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` file does appear to have the contents that it should.